# How Can I Take A Formula From One Cell And Display It In Another Cell?

Tags: google-sheets

When one cell references another that contains a formula, only the value is displayed. Is there a way to display the actual text of the formula in this second cell?

Here's a simulated version of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Cell A4 contains the SUM formula. Cell B4 displays the text that makes up the formula in cell A4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way, actually there are more than one. Here is one from [Google Sheets Function List](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en)

| Type | Name | Syntax | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Lookup | FORMULATEXT | FORMULATEXT(cell) | Returns the formula as a string. [Learn more](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365792?hl=en) |

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!